# Distribution Provisioning Profiles disappeared when i check the Authmatic Device Provisioning and do refresh

Tags: ios, adhoc, organizer

I'm using a Mac OS X leopard version 10.6.8.
XCode is 4.2 build 4C199 and we enrolled company iOS Developer Program a week ago.

I would be certain the certifications and provisioning files well but we are facing the problem, that the distribution provisioning profiles downloaded are disappeared when they do sync with dev portal by checking Automatic Device Provisioning box in Organizer of XCode.

These phenomenon is appearing only Adhoc and AppStore profiles.
The thing strange is the Development provisioning profiles only are showed in Organizer and work good.

why do you think we are having those problem? Anybody would sugest to us about that?

We should distribute our application by AdHoc and publishing to app store later, but we stopped this position....please help me.